# How to refer to imported API gateway while creating lambda event via serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm importing details of existing api gateway by using the plugin [plugins/serverless-import-apigateway](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-import-apigateway)

Below is my code.

```
service: name-${env:Environment}
frameworkVersion: "3"
 
    
plugins:
  - serverless-import-apigateway


#Using Custom variables
custom:
  account-id:
    dev: 
    qa: 
    prod: 
  importApiGateway:    #Here it is importing
    name: name-${env:Environment}
    resources:                                     
      - /new1/{id}/new2

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  iam:
    role:
      name: name-${env:Environment}
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:Query
          Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:${self:custom.account-id.${env:Environment}}:table/name-${env:Environment}"

functions:
  name-lambda:
    name:  name-${env:Environment}
    handler: index.handler
    environment:
      TableName: "name-${env:Environment}"
    events:
        - http:
            method: GET
            path: /new1/{id}/new2
```

While creating path it is creating new api gateway but in console it shows me it hs imported the api gateway and the resource path also already exits in the api gateway. I don't want it to create new api gateway or resource. Just use the existing ones. The documents of server less doesn't show how to use it.